# Wordpress redirect to similar link

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I have a problem
in wordpress that some links are redirected, even existing myite.com/page/item1
redirects to meusite.com.br/item-1
ignoring that there is a link to page / item-1
I accept help and appreciate personal attention.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you shifted your WordPress form one server to another.
Please go to setting and change permalinks to default then save it.

Comment: I did not change the server :( already tested, unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Please add more information to your question, so that I will be able to help you.